# image recognition in android/java

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am developing an application in android.In this application I want to find the shape of an object in a black and white snaps. If i have a triangular object in the snap then i want to find the angle between the edges of the objects programmatically. I do not want to draw the line manually on the object and find the angle. My actual need is that scan the image and find angle of the object using objects pixel intensity.

Can anyone please suggest me how to proceed for this work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenCV library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which [can be built for Android](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android), can perform such shape detection. Here's a [tutorial about triangle and other shapes detection](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp). It shows how to extract vertices, from which you should be able to get angles easily. It's in C# but should be easy to port to C.

I don't think that you'll find a ready-to-use OpenCV Java binding for Android. But using the Android NDK, you could encapsulate calls to the OpenCV C API, and expose a few functions in Java through JNI. A google search about ["opencv android java"](http://www.google.com/search?q=opencv%20android%20java) yields a couple of tips.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is a good solution for a mobile device, but it sounds like you should use a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find the lines, and then find a triangle using those lines.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use some [Edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection), Which is what Hough transform is part of. There are many different complex approaches to this process, but this is definitely a starting point to read up on.